# Is there free or discounted advertising for Open Source *organisations*?

Tags: discussion, product-support

I'm working with The Perl Foundation, a non-for-profit organisation - all volunteers - which is responsible for the Perl and Raku programming languages, as well as managing various community activities such as conferences.

We're currently running a survey looking into how we can support newcomers

https://news.perlfoundation.org/post/newperluserssurvey

Posting it in all the obvious places, LinkedIn, Facebook, IRC, mailing lists... is failing to find the target audience - people new to Perl. Here is the spread of the responses so far:

[image]

I know that people Googling for solutions to their problems will very often wind up on Stack Overflow, so I'm wondering whether it would be possible to advertise this survey on Stack Overflow, within the scope of our very limited budget.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can offer.

Comment: If you're solicing *development work*, then Stack Overflow provides free advertising. Otherwise, for a survey, I don't think so (nor do I think it should do so). I also don't think Stack Overflow will produce the target audience, either.

Comment: perhaps the target audience is not interested in a write-only language

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @CodyGray. Regarding the target audience, I'm pretty sure people looking for help will visit Stack Overflow to look at other peoples' answers to similar questions before writing their own.

Comment: what's the difference between a "non-for-profit", "not-for-profit" and "non-profit" organizations? If there's no difference, why not go with the shortest/simplest variant, or do folks really like typing that much?

Comment: non-profit says nothing about your intentions :-)

Comment: @oguzismail It's possible to write write-only code in any language, Perl just makes it easy.

Comment: StackOverflow does have [open source advertising](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising?tab=Newest) (uh, did have? I can't find posts for 2H 2020 or 2021). Not sure whether a survey advertisement would fit though.